# How to properly use ‘sich aufmachen’

Tags: grammar, word-order, separable-verb

When you are using *sich aufmachen* in the sense of *going out* or *heading out,* is this treated as a standard separable prefix verb?  I’ve only seen it used as such:

> Ich mache mich auf ins Studio.

or

> Er macht sich auf den Markt.

Is this correct? If so, then why isn’t *auf* placed at the end of the sentence like a normal separable prefix verb?  Like this:

> Er macht sich den Markt auf.

Comment: Aufstossen, ins Horn brechen, und auf den Weg machen...

Comment: In the market example you're missing a preposition for the market. The "auf" that's in there belongs to the verb, you need a second "auf" for "Markt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Er macht (sich) das Fenster/den Markt auf" hat den Sinn von öffnen.

"sich aufmachen nach + Zielort ist etwas anderes.

- Josef und Maria machten sich auf nach Bethlehem.

Das ist eine Kürzung von "Sie machten sich auf den Weg nach B". Wenn "den Weg" weggelassen wird, bleibt "auf" natürlich an seinem Platz.  Der Sinn von Beginn einer Bewegung bleibt somit erhalten und kann nicht mit "etwas öffnen" verwechselt werden.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I would use *sich aufmachen* without naming my destination.

> Ich mach mich jetzt auf. Wann kommst du nach?

But reading the question I acknowledge that it can be used with a destination aswell. Rogermue uses a nice, biblical example:

> Sie machten sich auf nach Bethlehem.

And I would likely also allow (among others!)

> Sie machen sich nach Bethlehem auf.

The thing about your market example is that it’s missing a preposition as Emanuel pointed out in the comment.

> Er macht sich auf den Markt.

sounds funny. It’ll either mean *he is making himself onto the market* (as in on the top of the market) or it’ll mean *he is opening the market for himself*, but that would have a better word order as you asked

> Er macht sich den Markt auf.

To give the sentence the meaning you intended, you need an *auf* from *aufmachen* and **another one** from *auf den Markt* to give:

> Er macht sich *auf* den Markt *auf*.

Compare with the perfect tense:

> Er hat sich *auf* den Markt *auf*gemacht.

---

And this is personal preference, but I would prefer

> Er geht jetzt los zum Markt

or something like that.

Comment: And also: er macht sich auf zum Markt:)